# Big Sur Time Machine only using ~3.5 gb to backup a fresh install

Tags: time-machine, big-sur

I previously had Catalina on my mac and a time machine backup was taking up the same size as the size of the usage on the drive.  I updated to a fresh install of Big Sur and now when I try to do a backup on the fresh install it is only taking up 3.5gb out of the total 20gb size of the drive.

Why is this the case?  Is time machine creating a full back up of my drive (including system files and everything)?  Will I be able to restore to this point whenever and get back to this same initial state of the fresh install?

I also noticed that in Disk Utility my non data partition seems to have what looks like a sub partition that is labeled com.apple.os.update-53281F3D.....

Pre and post Big Sur install disk images below.  The first image is before the the reinstall.  The second is after deleting the old partitions resulting in just one full partition and then installing from the bootable flash.

[image]

[image]

My install process was based on this post:  https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/clean-install-macos-3637409/

My installation steps were a follows:

1. created a boot flash drive using an image for Big Sur
2. formatted both partitions (data first, then non data partition)
3. installed from the boot flash drive created with Big Sur image from apple store

Comment: It likely isn't backing up your operating system. In Disk Utility, I expect the size of the "Data" volume will match the 3.5 GB you're seeing for Time Machine

Comment: You are correct.  But why would that be?  Do I need to do anything I have not marked anything to be excluded from the backup.

Comment: I also noticed that in Disk Utility my non data partition seems to have a subpartition that is labeled com.apple.os.update-53281F3D.....  I created a boot flash drive using an image for Big Sur.  I will update the post to add this detail in case it is relevant to the question.

Comment: Everything here sounds normal, it’s not backing up your operating system because your operating system can’t change so it does not need to be

Comment: The com.apple.os.update is normal as well